# Why does this QML code have poor performance?

Tags: qml, qtquick2

If QML rendering is hardware accelerated, shouldn't this simple example outperform the equivalent implementation in Qt classic?

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


    Column {
        id: cc
        property real val: 0

        Row {
            spacing: 10
            TextField {
                id: numRows
                text: "1"
                property int value: parseInt(text);
                validator: IntValidator { bottom: 1; top: 100; }

            }
            TextField {
                id: numCols
                text: "1"
                property int value: parseInt(text);
                validator: IntValidator { bottom: 1; top: 100; }
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: numRows.value

            Row {
                Repeater {
                    model: numCols.value
                    Slider {
                        width: app.width / numCols.value
                        height: 18.5
                        value: cc.val
                        onValueChanged: cc.val = value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I idea is to fill the screen with rows and columns of sliders, and have each slider connect to every other slider.  For my screen I use 55 rows and 20 columns.  As I move a slider, I expect to see a fluid motion of all the sliders on the screen, yet the frame rate is very low (I would guess 5 to 10 fps).  I have a very beefy GPU, and I was expecting much better performance.  What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using the OpenGL or ANGLE build?

Comment: @ddriver I'm pretty sure it's the OpenGL build.  Is there a big difference in performance between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this under a (CPU, not QML) profiler, the majority of the time spent is actually in rendering the `Slider` items using native styling. If performance is an important issue, and native desktop styling is not, I would suggest not using QtQuickControls 1, as the styling has a significant amount of overhead.

If I update your example to use QtQuickControls 2, it is significantly smoother:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


    Column {
        id: cc
        property real val: 0

        Row {
            spacing: 10
            TextField {
                id: numRows
                text: "1"
                property int value: parseInt(text);
                validator: IntValidator { bottom: 1; top: 100; }

            }
            TextField {
                id: numCols
                text: "1"
                property int value: parseInt(text);
                validator: IntValidator { bottom: 1; top: 100; }
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: numRows.value

            Row {
                Repeater {
                    model: numCols.value
                    Slider {
                        width: app.width / numCols.value
                        height: 18.5
                        value: cc.val
                        onPositionChanged: cc.val = position
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get yourself 1100 sliders, you are asking to continuously update 1100 sliders. That is a lot of signals being sent. I will not ask you what you need 1100 synchronized sliders for ...

Although you can inch out a few cycles by only updating `cc.val` when the slider is pressed, this will not change very much.

All in all, you can only seriously reduce the work being done by choosing a `stepSize` or setting `updateValueWhileDragging: false`. You will still see a delay when you release a slider, but the frame rate will not disturb the experience as much.

Comment: The cost of a signal is the same as the cost of about 10 function calls, so I don't think that's an issue.  I don't need 1100 sliders, obviously, but I'm trying to compare rendering performance.  Given that there is hardware acceleration with Qt Quick, I was expecting to see this QML code to run at high frame rates.

Comment: You should run your code and attach the QML Profiler to the process.
(in QtCreator click on 'Analyze' and hit the 'Start' button in QML Profiler view)
It'll show you that it takes a lot of time to process one single mouse event. For me it takes something about 23 to 27 msecs.

Comment: In worst case that code is executed for every pixel you move the mouse.

Because that code is run from inside the event loop the next mouse event cannot get processed as long as you are in that function but they will get queued up.

All-in-all rendering has the smallest impact in that case. Try to find an other way for your benchmark